# Spark Cassandra Connector with java WARN message for ConnectionInitException

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I keep getting this WARN messages for spark project when i run the cassandra job

```
WARN ChannelPool: [s0|/172.17.0.3:9042]  Error while opening new channel (ConnectionInitException: [s0|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.5.0, CLIENT_ID=ef6bf95c-e93f-4f59-860a-829ae07e80cb, APPLICATION_NAME=Spark-Cassandra-Connector-local-1593841648738}): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException))
```

i dont see any data loss but i'm not also sure why this happens

i have 3 node cassandra docker running in my pc

cassandra version :- 3.11.6
spark version :- 2.4.6
java : jdk8

keyspace info :

```
keyspace_name    durable_writes        replication
mykeyspace          true           {class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy, datacenter1=1, datacenter2=1}
```

Comment: look for the errors on the Cassandra side. For example, you may not have enough file descriptors, etc.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt : now when i look closely to the message above i see that the configured ip is not whats its giving error for. i didnt find any entry for the ip mentioned in my project . not sure where its comming from ! the same is happening when i change details for ES ip from localhost to anyother ip

Comment: Driver is doing connect to one node, and then discovers the whole cluster - it could be one of the Cassandra nodes...

Comment: Maybe that ip could be your machine's internal IP. run ipconfig / ifconfig to find out

Comment: @SuhasNM this is happening coz i'm running cassandra on docker in another system, with 3 node cluster and my application is connecting using system ip which is causing this issue.

Comment: Connect to the IP of another machine and specify the port. Make sure that the port is accessible from the machine where you are trying to run your code.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am also getting same thing. My cluster is in kubernetes and I access the cluster via a ELB. Seeing the warning it appears that the driver is trying to connect to other cluster nodes. Also, my app (spring boot) is taking time to startup.

Comment: How to throw this error ? I'm facing same error. I need to handle it. #cassandra

Comment: @wnlfnb I don't think you can catch this error as it's not stopping your application from working with Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question!

So to solve this we need to get into the docker networking, And map your containers IP to broadcast from eth0 to external world.

Below link could be of some help

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

To be frank, I haven't explored the whole docker networking myself as we eneded up not using docker for Cassandra in our case.